# Best way to represent n-level deep nested XMLnodes with same name?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-database

I'm writing an XML parser in C# .Net and for this particular chunk of XML I'm having a difficult time conceptualizing how I would parse and store it's relationship in a database. See sample xml below:

```
<Article name="x" date="y">
    <Words>
        <Category ID="1000" Name="Person">
            <Keyword ID="1124" Name="Adult">
                <Keyword ID="1125" Name="Female" />
            </Keyword>
        </Category>
        <Category ID="1000" Name="Person">
            <Keyword ID="1124" Name="Adult">
                  <Keyword ID="1126" Name="Male" />
            </Keyword>
        </Category>
    </Words>
</Article>
```

So you can see there are **N Categories** each containing **N nested keyword nodes**. What is the best way to represent this relational data?

I have a master XML doc of all the possible Keyword and Category combinations. This is my first thought but please correct me if there is a better way:

1. Table for all Keywords/Categories: ID, Name, ParentID
2. Table for Article: ID, Name, Date,
3. Go to bottom most keyword node in each category node and add to lookup table: ID, ArticleID, KeywordID

Then I could just do a join and recursively find all the parents of the bottom most keyword node.

Comment: You have xml, you have database table. What kind of representation you need?

Comment: Actually, I guess my real question is how in C# would you get to the last descendant Keyword Node in each Category node?

Comment: You need to get `Male` and `Female` elements from this xml? Without getting `Adult` element?

Comment: Correct. A way to only grab the bottom most <keyword> node values.. ignoring the parent ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get only bottom most keywords, then you can simply check if keyword element contains any child nodes before selecting it:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var keywords = from k in xdoc.Descendants("Keyword")
               where !k.Elements().Any()
               select new
               {
                   ID = (int)k.Attribute("ID"),
                   Name = (string)k.Attribute("Name")
               };
```

Output:

```
{ ID = 1125, Name = Female }
{ ID = 1126, Name = Male }
```

UPDATE: XPath solution to get leaf Keyword elements

```
var keywords = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//Keyword[not(*)]");
```